# Symptoms of diphtheria in cats

Tags: cats, diseases

Diphtheria is considered to be one of the few diseases transmittable between cats/humans. This disease doesn't really exist (anymore) in most of the world, but is unfortunately prevalent (but thankfully not so common anymore) in some developing countries. The reason diphtheria is considered troublesome is initially it just appears like a common cold/cough.

I have tried searching the web quite a bit, but everything I find is about the symptoms of the disease in humans. I want to understand what the symptoms of diphtheria are, in cats.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphtheria#Transmission and here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3321947/

Comment: the last link gives a lot more information than you ask but i think somebody with medical knowledge needs to answer this,i do understand most of it but i do not think i can make an answer from the information.

Comment: Hi, I had a good look at the last link and it seems to be more about a specific cat with a wide variety of symptoms (many of which seem to have nothing with diphtheria - which is primarily a respiratory tract disorder). I think the right person to answer would be someone with veterinary knowledge from a developing country where cats commonly have diphtheria. I think the reason relevant info on this is hard to find online is this topic is simply not that relevant in most developed countries.

Comment: it does say they did not know cats could be carriers of  diphteria and that they  could not find the source for how the cat got infected as the owners was not carriers of the infection(so diphteria in cats is even more rare than it is in humans).if i understand it correctly.